# Updating my SQL database with dynamic content

Tags: php, html, sql

My HTML table below is generated based on the size of each users' table. How do I update my SQL table so that I can add many inputs as HTML table generates?

$num generates the number of text boxes that the user will need to fill. I want to update my sql table with all the data that the user inputs.

```html
$num = 0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $num = $num+1;    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['producto'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<input type = "text" name = "cantidad' .  $num . '" value = "" size = "40" />' . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<input type = "text" name = "precio' .  $num . '" value = "" size = "40" />' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It looks like you are populating a table with the contents of an SQL table. To put the contents that the table generates back into an SQL table would be needless, since they are already in there, correct?

Comment: did you mean "how to update" your database table with new value cantidad and precio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max)
IF(checkYourCondition)
BEGIN
SET @SQL=' '+@username +'  '+@producto +'  '
END
set @SQL = @SQL + ' '
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

Comment: please use like this